# cmake finds library but not included in generated makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am attempting to use CMake to compile a multi-file C++ project that uses boost. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) # only find static libs
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS serialization)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_executable(RandomFor RandomFor.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(RandomFor ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

When I run cmake .. I get the following output

cmake ..

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:492 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:494 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:496 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:498 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = OFF
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:500 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:502 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:554 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:556 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:558 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:560 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:562 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:655 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:679 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.53.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:755 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc48
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:808 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:810 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:859 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;NO_DEFAULT_PATH
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:947 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_serialization-gcc48-mt-1_53;boost_serialization-gcc48-mt;boost_serialization-mt-1_53;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:983 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_serialization-gcc48-mt-d-1_53;boost_serialization-gcc48-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt-d-1_53;boost_serialization-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1034 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/build
```

It seems to find the serialization library as expected. When I run make, I get an error trying to build indicating that it can't find serialization.hpp:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/RandomFor.cpp.o
In file included from /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/SerializeHelper.h:1:0,
                 from /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/RandomFor.cpp:14:
/home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/ITreeNode.h:5:49: fatal error: boost\serialization\serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "boost\serialization\serialization.hpp"
                                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/RandomFor.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the Makefile that cmake generated:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running interactive CMake command-line interface..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -i .
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/build/CMakeFiles /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/tladd/SeniorDesign/RandomForest/RandomForest/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named RandomFor

# Build rule for target.
RandomFor: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 RandomFor
.PHONY : RandomFor

# fast build rule for target.
RandomFor/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/build
.PHONY : RandomFor/fast

RandomFor.o: RandomFor.cpp.o
.PHONY : RandomFor.o

# target to build an object file
RandomFor.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/RandomFor.cpp.o
.PHONY : RandomFor.cpp.o

RandomFor.i: RandomFor.cpp.i
.PHONY : RandomFor.i

# target to preprocess a source file
RandomFor.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/RandomFor.cpp.i
.PHONY : RandomFor.cpp.i

RandomFor.s: RandomFor.cpp.s
.PHONY : RandomFor.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
RandomFor.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/RandomFor.dir/RandomFor.cpp.s
.PHONY : RandomFor.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... RandomFor"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... RandomFor.o"
    @echo "... RandomFor.i"
    @echo "... RandomFor.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

which doesn't seem to include any mention of Boost. Any help on why the generated Makefile isn't working?

Comment: Single backslash versus forward slash. Have you tried escaping the backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on what compiler (and maybe OS) you try to compile you must not use backslashes in your include directives.

try to include like this:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
```

Comment: Thanks so much; that was the problem